# morgan substitute a "-" if a value is not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, backend, morgan

```
morgan(
    ":remote-addr :method :url :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms"
);
```

For example, if `:res[content-length]` is not available, then it will print a "-" in its place. How do I change this dash to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"-"` is hardcoded in the `compile` function [here](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L407) which runs when the value behind the token is `undefined`.

The [`tokens` method](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#tokens) can be used to provide a custom string when the value behind the token is missing, i.e. `undefined`. You can use it to overwrite predefined tokens used in your format string passed to `morgan`. Here is an example overwriting the predefined `:res` token and replacing the `-` with `<!>` if the token value is `undefined`.

```js
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')

const app = express()
const origRes = morgan.res

morgan.token('res', function customGetResponseHeader(req, res, field) {
  const resp = origRes(req, res, field)

  if (resp === undefined) {
    // Custom string here
    return '<!>'
  }
})

app.use(morgan(":remote-addr :method :url :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms"))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})

app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
 console.log('listening')
})
```